# Replace Foreign key with Description in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table A , having 20 columns,

```
col1, col2, col3....etc
```

and each column referencing value of a *foreign key* of another table that is as follows:

```
fkey1  - Description1 
fkey2  - Description2 
fkey3  - Description2
```

Is there any way to get the description without going for join on each of the 20 columns.
Basically is there a quick short way to get the description in the output without going for `joins/case-when-then` ?

Comment: Why is doing the join an issue?  This is the standard way to combine data from two tables inside SQL.

Comment: Not an issue - was just hoping to find some shortcut ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use trigger on your child table ...

create trigger on your table after insert ..

and in this you can select description from your master table and can update your child table with this value....

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. Create a view that performs these joins.
2. Do not use reference tables and save the description in your primary table.

Answer (score 0):

If you problem is an explicit join, you can do a correlated subquery:

```
select id1, (select description from id1table where t.id1 = idtable.id),
       ...
from id1table
```

Operationally, though, this is just another syntax for the join.